# scikit-learn metrics on a subset of classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

We're using `scikit-learn==0.15.2` and training `LinearSVC` on 9 classes and a special 'others' class. The 'others' class contain anything in our dataset which does not fit into the 9 important classes we are trying to classify.

We would like to get average micro/macro precision/recall/f1 metrics on only the 9 classes, without the 'others' class, in order to get a performance estimation for our classifier.

We've failed to find any support for that in the built-in scikit `metrics` functions. And even the `classification_report` function has an issue when trying to restrict the labels to only the 9 (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/3123).

Is this lack of support indicating that our fundamental approach isn't correct? Should we include the 'others' when we measure performance?

EDIT: Note that our consumer uses our predictions only when we predict one of the 9 classes. If we predict 'others' our output is thrown away and another model is used.

Answer (score 3):

In short **yes, you should include each class**. Why would you ignore the (probably the biggest) class? Even if it is just noise it is fundamental to classifiers performance to actually be able to distinguish the noise from important classes. There might be situations where you are not interested in "others" class (in cases when False Positives are irrelevant) but these situations are quite rare and so are not directly implemented in scikit-learn's metrics module.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use confusion matrix http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html ?

Based on that matrix you can create your own metrics